# Splitting all line features into equal parts using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, line, splitting

Using ArcGIS Pro, I have a matrix of roads clipped for a County and looking to split this line feature into 3 equal parts (e.g., east, central, west). The split options in the Toolbox seem to only split polygons and the editing split tool will only split single line features.

Is there a method for splitting an entire line shapefile into 3 equal segments?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the option to [split into equal parts](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/divide-a-polyline-by-a-value.htm) that's found as part of the editing tools.

To apply this to every single line in a file, consider writing a python script that uses a [Search Cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) to iterate through each line feature so you can edit the features one by one in an automated fashion.